# Diff two files in different formats TXT/JSON

Tags: json, linux, bash, text, diff

I have two files which contain similar data but in different formats (JSON/TXT).

file-A.json

```
        {
        "Name": "www.mydomain.com.",
        "Type": "A",
        "TTL": 600,
        "ResourceRecords": [
            {
                "Value": "8.8.8.8"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Name": "other.domain.com.",
        "Type": "NS",
        "TTL": 1800,
        "ResourceRecords": [
            {
                "Value": "123.reg."
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

file-B.txt

```
www.mydomain.com 600 IN A 8.8.8.8
other.domain.com 1800 IN NS 123.reg.
```

I'm trying to figure out the best method to diff both files so i can see if those records exist/match. However, as they are in different formats i'm not sure this is possible, so my idea was to parse both files to have an identical format then run diff on them but i don't know how to even start.

I've been able to parse the json using jq to obtain specific records

```
cat file-B.json | jq '.ResourceRecordSets[] | {"Name": .Name,"ResourceRecords": .[]}'
```

but starting to think this is not even the best approach.

Comment: Just to note, i'm a junior so apologies if this is even the wrong way to think or go about this.

Comment: Something like: `jq -r '.[]|.Name+" "+(.TTL|tostring)+" IN "+.Type+" "+.ResourceRecords[0].Value' file-A.json | diff - file-B.txt` would probably do.

Comment: Thank you for your response!

When trying the above i get the below error for the json:

 ```jq -r '.[]|.Name+" "+(.TTL|tostring)+" IN "+.Type+" "+.ResourceRecords[0].Value' file-A.json | diff - file-B.txt
jq: error (at file-A.json:10): Cannot index string with string "ResourceRecords"
parse error: Expected value before ',' at line 10, column 6
0a1,3
> www.mydomain.com 600 IN A 8.8.8.8
> other.domain.com 1800 IN NS 123.reg.
>
```

Comment: Then your file-A is malformed JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main approach is to get both data in the same format.

So lets convert the JSON file to the same format as that of the text file with the help of `jq`:

```sh
jq -r '
# For all array entries
.[] | 
  # Concatenates values to compose a flat DNS zone text file
  .Name +
  " " +
  (.TTL|tostring) +
  " IN " +
  .Type +
  " " +
  .ResourceRecords[0].Value
' \
file-A.json |
  diff - file-B.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In addtional to Léa's answer this also worked by converting the json to a similar zonefile

```
jq -jr '.ResourceRecordSets[] | "\(.Name) \t\(.TTL) \t\(.Type) \t\(.ResourceRecords[]?.Value)\n"' file-A.json

www.mydomain.com. 600 IN A 8.8.8.8
other.domain.com. 1800 IN NS 123.reg.
```

I could then export the output to a file and do a diff OR just pipe it directly to a diff as Léa demonstrated. We could also `sort` this if needed to get accurate diff but not sure it's needed.